# Show listview from viewbag's list in MVC4

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc-4

I have taken list in viewbag in controller as follows:

```
List<TEAMS_PP.Entity.account> list = new TeacherEval().AllTechersList();
            ViewBag.allteacherlist = list;
```

I have made sure that list do come in ViewBag.allteacherlist.

I wanted to show it in listview on view page(cshtml)

I made following code:

```
@(Html.Kendo().ListView<ViewBag.allteacherlist>()
    .Name("ListView")
    .TagName("div")
    .ClientTemplateId("template")
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Read(read => read.Action("Products_Read", "Home")) // Specify the action method and controller name
    )
    .Pageable()
)
```

But i am not able to access viewbag.allteacherlist over here.

I just want to display list comming in viewbag on the page.

What can i do???

Please help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the correct syntax

```
@(Html.Kendo().ListView<TEAMS_PP.Entity.account>(ViewBag.allteacherlist as IEnumerable<TEAMS_PP.Entity.account>)
    .Name("ListView")
    .TagName("div")
    .ClientTemplateId("template")
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Read(read => read.Action("Products_Read", "Home")) // Specify the action method and controller name
    )
    .Pageable()
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
@(Html.Kendo().ListView<(List<TEAMS_PP.Entity.account>)ViewBag.allteacherlist>()
    .Name("ListView")
    .TagName("div")
    .ClientTemplateId("template")
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Read(read => read.Action("Products_Read", "Home")) // Specify the action method and controller name
    )
    .Pageable()
)
```